# How to kill a nohup process?

Tags: bash, process, kill, nohup

I executed the following command

```
$ nohup ./tests.run.pl 0 &
```

now when I try to kill it (and the executions that are started from this script) using

```
$ kill -0 <process_id>
```

it does not work. How can I kill a nohupped process and the processes that runs via the nohupped script?

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`kill -0` does *not* kill the process. It just checks if you could send a signal to it.

Simply `kill pid`, and if that doesn't work, try `kill -9 pid`.

Comment: @Mat, Do I need to get the process id first? What if I run multiple processes and wish to kill them all at once? I did parallel computing using multiple cores, so there are, say 10 processes invoked by "nohup". I wish to kill them all. Could you please instruct me here? Thanks.

Comment: i have killed a nohup process with kill -9,but still when i run command tail f nohup.out i m getting logs continuously...this means my process is running..what to do??

Answer (score 30):

Simply `kill <pid>` which will send a `SIGTERM`, which `nohup` won't ignore.

You should not send a `SIGKILL` first as that gives the process no chance to recover; you should try the following, in order:

- `SIGTERM` (15)
- `SIGINT` (2)
- `SIGKILL` (9)

Comment: Absolutely true.  A SIGKILL (kill -9) can't be caught by a process's signal handlers.  This means that you can't write any epilog code to  remove temporary files and/or detach any shared memory segments allocated.  Failure to cleanup shared memory means less overall memory is available for new processes -- a nasty thing.

Answer (score 16):

I would do something like:

```
jobs

[1] + Running nohup ./tests.run.pl

kill %1
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the process ids and it might run various commands within a shell (or a loop), you can run `jobs -l` to list jobs and PIDs, then `kill` them.

See example:

```
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$ jobs -l
[1]  27398 Running                 nohup ./extract_assessor_01.sh > job1.log &
[2]  27474 Running                 nohup ./extract_assessor_02.sh > job2.log &
[3]  27478 Running                 nohup ./extract_assessor_03.sh > job3.log &
[4]- 27481 Running                 nohup ./extract_assessor_04.sh > job4.log &
[5]+ 28664 Running                 nohup ./extract_assessor_01.sh > job1.log &
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$ sudo kill 27398
sudo kill 27474[1]   Terminated              nohup ./extract_assessor_01.sh > job1.log
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$ sudo kill 27474
[2]   Terminated              nohup ./extract_assessor_02.sh > job2.log
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$ sudo kill 27478
[3]   Terminated              nohup ./extract_assessor_03.sh > job3.log
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$ sudo kill 27481
[4]-  Terminated              nohup ./extract_assessor_04.sh > job4.log
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$ sudo kill 28664
[5]+  Terminated              nohup ./extract_assessor_01.sh > job1.log
ubuntu@app2:/usr/share/etlservice/bin$
```

Answer (score 3):

kill `nohup` process

```
ps aux |grep nohup
```

grep that `PID` 
`kill -15 -1 16000` (will logout you) and clean on next login root