# How to kill a NOHUP process for Node.js launched via SSH

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, bash, ssh

I start `node.js` server has **3000** port by nohup for background running, but now i want to stop the `node.js` server with **3000** and start again with the same port. How can I stop the process?

i can use this command for get the process to kill;

```
ps -a","ps -ef |grep nohup
```

but it return;

```
-bash: kill: (11929) - No such process
```

thanks

Comment: You can get PID by using `pgrep 'nohup'` and use `kill` command. **(OR)** `pgrep 'nohup' | xargs kill` **(OR)** `pkill nohup`

Comment: If I were you I'd just use something like `tmux`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally i got an solution for kill the node server which is run under nohup process

by the help of

start server @ background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4018223/2616818

pid: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152730

Kill: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8007409/2616818

1.Get the node process id by use

```
ps -ef | grep "node"
//9500 pts/0  00:00:00 .node.bin
```

2.Kill the process by

```
kill 9500
//you can use the PID to kill if not use kill -9 pid
```

for advanced use [forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever)

Comment: Thanks, but I ran node via "nohup forever server.js" and when I run your command to see process, it tells the pid number, but cannot kill it because its always increasing! please help me

Comment: use this "kill -9 pid"

Comment: but pid is always increasing!

Comment: if its an linux then we can do `lsof -i` it will list the port which was running